# jQuery: how to hide button (add more) after Append 3 item and show button if remove one item from 3 item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery:
How to hide button (add more) after Append 3 item and show button if remove one item from 3 item ?

```
 $('.addMoreElement').each(function () {
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    $(".appendedBefore").before(`
    <div class="row position-relative thisLength">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Departing</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar-alt"></i>
            <input type='text' class='select-date form-control' placeholder="Select Date" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="removethis"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
    </div>
    `);

      $('.form-group').find(".select-date").datepicker();
      $('.form-group').find('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');

    if ($(".thisLength").length >= 1) {
      alert('NMoklidsjfkolsdmf')
      $('.addMoreElement').hide();
    }
  });                                                  
});
```

Comment: Side note; the outer most `each()` is unnecessary.  `on()` will implicitly bind to all element in the jQuery result stack already.

Comment: You already have this line: `if ($(".thisLength").length >= 1) {`.  Which could be changed to check for 3 instead of one.  So what difficulty are you having with making a delegate event binding for the `.removethis` to then check if the length is < 3 and show it again?

Comment: Your code looks right. Can you share the html code of your button (add more)?

Comment: This code html and jQuery jsFiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/Omar_Shaheen/mnc2koud/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are looking for similar like this it will work fine.You can add three elements

Once it reached it's limit add button will disappear and if you remove any one element add

button will appear again.Instead of input field you can add your html content.

```js
    var maxField  = 3; 
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); 
    var wrapper   = $('.field_wrapper'); 
    var fieldHTML = '<div><input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button">Remove</a></div>';
    var x = 0; 
    
    $(addButton).click(function(){
      if(x < maxField){ 
        x++; 
        if(x<=3)
          $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); 
        if(x==3)
          $('.add_button').hide();
      }
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent('div').remove(); 
      x--; 
      if(x<3)
        $('.add_button').show();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="field_wrapper">
    <div>
        <!--<input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>-->
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">Add Item</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, This is a great answer, It works well for me. https://jsfiddle.net/Omar_Shaheen/0gom8kLb/2/